# iptables Source NAT with Multiple NIC & Public IP Addresses Not Working

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, nat, nic

I just have a problem on the multiple NIC & IP addresses server. I've configured my Cent OS 7 server with an additional public IP address which belongs to eth1. When iptables source NAT enabled, only the additional IP address couldn't be used.

In this post, two public IP addresses are indicated by 99.0.1.100 (eth0) and 99.0.2.100 (eth1). Subnet-mask of 99.0.2.100 is 255.255.254.0, default gateway is set properly (99.0.1.1 for 99.0.1.100, 99.0.2.1 for 99.0.2.100).

---

below is contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`. (HWADDR is censored)

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
HWADDR=**:**:**:**:**:**
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=99.0.2.100
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
```

below is output of `ip route`.

```
default via 99.0.1.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
99.0.1.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 99.0.1.100 metric 100
99.0.2.0/23 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 99.0.2.100
```

below is output of `ip rule`.

```
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 99.0.2.100 lookup subroute-eth1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

below is contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1`.

```
default via 99.0.2.1 table subroute-eth1
```

below is contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1`.

```
from 99.0.2.100 table subroute-eth1
```

then, the following request has been sent properly and responded proper IP address as string for each public IP addresses.

```
# curl --interface eth0 api.ipify.org  # outputs 99.0.1.100
# curl --interface eth1 api.ipify.org  # outputs 99.0.2.100
```

---

here, I want each users of the system use different public IP address. So applied the following iptables source NAT. Where uid=1000 is A, uid=1001 is B, respectively.

```
# iptables -t nat -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 99.0.1.100
# iptables -t nat -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 99.0.2.100
```

in this situation, eth0 works correctly, but eth1 has timed out.

```
# curl api.ipify.org  # outputs 99.0.1.100
# sudo -u A curl api.ipify.org  # outputs 99.0.1.100
# sudo -u B curl api.ipify.org  # **time out**
```

I have no idea what is wrong because of lack of network experience. If anyone has ideas, help me, please.
Note that in this situation, `ssh root@99.0.2.100` from Internet is still working properly.

---

**Edit**: below is output of `ip route show table subroute-eth1`

```
default via 99.0.2.1 dev eth1
```

Comment: Of all you wrote, I never saw the content of table subroute-eth1. could you add the result of `ip route show table subroute-eth1` ? Or maybe it's empty and you didn't realize it?

Comment: You certainly redacted yours IPs, but `99.0.1.0/23` is an invalid route, it should be `99.0.0.0/23` (`99.0.2.0/23` is fine), just to keep a reproducible case in the question.

Comment: I went ahead and made a working answer: as you can see it's not trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uid should trigger a routing change to use `eth1` instead of `eth0`. `nat/POSTROUTING`'s SNAT (while still needed) comes too late for this because as the name POSTROUTING implies it happens after the routing decisions: the network interface is chosen and won't change anymore.

For local traffic the rule has to happen in the `mangle/OUTPUT` chain to alter the route, by using marks which can trigger an `ip rule` lookup:

```
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j MARK --set-mark 1001
```

The information is then reused via `ip rule`. Even 1000 has to be considered (to handle the specific case `uid1000$ curl --interface eth1 http://api.ipify.org/` which should not use entry 32765):

```
ip rule add fwmark 1000 lookup main
ip rule add fwmark 1001 lookup subroute-eth1
```

Note that the initial default IP was chosen before: SNAT is still needed to fix it to the new correct one. Why using this mark since there's already a rule with `from 99.0.2.100 lookup subroute-eth1` then? Again that's because of the order of various evaluations in the network stack, as summarized by this [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg): only a change in `mangle/OUTPUT` can trigger the *reroute check* seen in the schematic, and by this time the IP hasn't been corrected to 99.0.2.100.

In the reverse path, some network elements will not know about those routing tables in time anyway, loose mode has to be set on `eth1`'s [rp_filter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-4.14.y#n1124) or return packets will be dropped:

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/rp_filter
```

Same for `eth0` to handle the specific case for uid 1000 above (`uid1000$ curl --interface eth1 http://api.ipify.org/`):

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
```

With this it should *mostly* work. But actually a few packets aren't owned by uid 1001: `TCP RST`, last `ACK` once the process has ended, or for UDP, related ICMP errors... are owned only by the kernel. They won't match uid 1001, will be sent on the wrong interface (with the wrong IP on this wrong interface) and this will create some timeouts at the end of the connections, more probably at the remote side rather than locally. This can be seen by doing a `kill -KILL` on a client with an altered connection made with user 1001 via `eth1`, and witnessing several retry `ACK` packets with source 99.0.2.100 sent via `eth0` (instead of `eth1`) acknowledging the `FIN` from remote received several times on `eth1`.

So all this has to be reworked using [`CONNMARK`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#CONNMARK) to track *flows* initiated by the user, instead of *packets* initiated by the user (some explanations [here](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/netfilter-connmark/)). `nat` doesn't have to change, since only the 1st packet in `NEW` state goes through iptables rules anyway and it's tracking flows already. Let's start over:

```
# iptables -t mangle -F
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j MARK --set-mark 1000
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j MARK --set-mark 1001
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Everything should behave correctly now.

Final note: while it wasn't needed in your setting, the link local route for eth1 should be duplicated on the table `subroute-eth1`, else accessing `eth1`'s LAN from uid 1001 will give strange results, because rule 32765 is read before rule 32766 so there won't ever be the link local route defined, as the result of this command shows:

```
# ip route get 99.0.2.55 mark 1001
99.0.2.55 via 99.0.2.1 dev eth1 table subroute-eth1 src 99.0.2.100 mark 0x3e9 uid 0 \    cache
```

It might prevent access to all of the LAN except the gateway.

You should add (or put as appropriate in the system configuration files):

```
ip route add table subroute-eth1 99.0.2.0/23 dev eth1 scope link src 99.0.2.100
```

And then the previous `ip route get` command will give instead the correct:

```
99.0.2.55 dev eth1 table subroute-eth1 src 99.0.2.100 mark 0x3e9 uid 0 \    cache
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved the problem. I'll try more than 2 IPs by referencing your answer.

Comment: Meanwhile better methods came to my attention. This can probably be solved completely without the use of iptables and netfilter: only using `ip rule add ... uidrange ...` should be enough. Check this answer of mine on UL SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564163/routing-traffic-for-a-user-through-specific-interface-tum1/564196#564196 . Doesn't require marks, doesn't make the application believe it's using an other IP, doesn't disrupt UDP services etc.